# Arduino to Android Adb(Microbridge) recieves lets app crash, but sending data is ok

Tags: java, android, c, arduino, adb

I'm using an Arduino with a USB hostshield (sparkfun) that is connected to a Android Phone. When I send data from the smartphone to the arduino then there is no problem. But when I send data from the arduino to the Android smartphone then the data is recieved (I get a message that the handler is triggerd) but the app crashes after a few cycles. I use de Adb library form Microbridge.

The data that is send from the arduino is as `uint16_t` with the number 800, this happens in the following loop (setup also included):

```
void setup()
{
   Serial.begin(57600);

   // Record time for sensor polling timer
   lastTime = millis();

  // Init the ADB subsystem.
  ADB::init();

 // Open an ADB stream to the phone's shell. Auto-reconnect. Use port number 4568
 connection = ADB::addConnection("tcp:4568", true, adbEventHandler);  

 Serial.println("Ready!");
}


void loop()
{
  //Check if sensor should be sampled.
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > 1000)
  {

   int number = 800;
   uint16_t data = number;
   Serial.println("Before send");
   connection->write(sizeof(data), (uint8_t*)&data);
   Serial.println("After send");

   // Update timer for sensor check
   lastTime = millis();
}

  // Poll the ADB subsystem.
  ADB::poll();
}
```

The data is recieved on the Android in the handler as followd (it uses the lightwight server from Microbridge):

```
server.addListener(new AbstractServerListener() {


@Override
public void onReceive(com.example.communicationmodulebase.Client client, byte[] data){

    Log.e(TAG, "In handler!");
   if (data.length < 1){
  return;
  }

    TextView textRecvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RecvStatusText);

    textRecvStatus.setText("In handler!");

   }
});
```

The message: "In handler!" is shown but after a few recieves the app chrases.

Does anyone have a idea why the app crashes? I can't read the catlog since the Android smartphone is connected to the arduino shield. As far as I know there is no way to show the catlog data(I could be wrong).

Any suggestions and tips are welcome!

Comment: I found out that the connection is oke but the app crashes because of the text setting in the text box after recieving. Doe anybody know why this is? ( The message "In heandler crashes the app")

Comment: Do i need a UI thread to display the data (updating the textview)?